# Unable to change the pivot data source with below code, not getting error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to change the data source of all the pivot tables in an Excel file. Consider that the data range is same and data is located in same file. Data range is assigned to string variable `newDataSource`.

```
 
    For Each ws In SourceWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In SourceWorkbook.PivotTables
    If Not bCreated Then

        pt.ChangePivotCache SourceWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=newDataSource)
            Set pc = pt.PivotCache
            bCreated = True
 
    Else
    If pt.CacheIndex <> pc.Index Then pt.CacheIndex = pc.Index

    End If
    Next pt
Next ws
```